# how to get position of Draggable element relative to Droppable that isOver? in Sortable too

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tree, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2Nf1.png)

## What I want to achieve:

when draggable element is over a droppable, I want to know how far away my mouse is from center/top border/ bottom border of that droppable. For example:
if  proximity of draggable to center of droppable is between 0.5 and 1, then make draggable child,
otherwise
if pointer is closer to top/bottom corner, then add draggable before/after that droppable(sortable) item.

## My goal is getting the experience Notion is giving:

close to center, then nest the file.
otherwise, then sort before or after
[GIF OF WHAT I WANT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQOd0.gif)

#### What I tried:

Ive played with Sortable Tree example and tried to understand implementation. That example defines being child based of offsetLeft value/ indentationWidth.

```
function handleDragMove({ delta, over, collisions, activatorEvent }: DragMoveEvent) {
    console.log("delta", delta.x, delta.y); //position of mouse from drag start point
    over && over.rect && console.log("over.rect", over.rect);
    // position of element that pointer is over of (relative to entire screen)
}
```

So I thought using clientX, clientY values instead of delta to compare with over.rect values and calculate proximity to center. But everthing I can think of feels hacky and gonna have other errors when scrolling and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I figured out how to check for center, but still would love to have further guidance on implementing the whole functionality.

```
function handleDragMove({ over, active }: DragMoveEvent) {
    let draggableCenterY;
    if (active.rect.current.translated) {
        draggableCenterY = active.rect.current.translated?.top + active.rect.current.translated?.height / 2;
    }
    let overCenterY;
    if(over){
        overCenterY = over.rect.top + over.rect.height / 2;
    }

    console.log('draggableCenterY: ', draggableCenterY)
    console.log('overCenterY', overCenterY)
}
```